# Creating video from images with jcodec (error)

Tags: android, bitmap, jcodec

I'm trying to use **jcodec library** to create video from images but ***sequenceEncoder.encodeImage(bitmap)*** is showing error.

my code for encoding is :-

```
class EncodeImages extends AsyncTask<File, Integer, Integer>{

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(File... params) {
            SequenceEncoder sequenceEncoder;

            try {
                sequenceEncoder = new SequenceEncoder(new File(params[0].getParentFile(),"Frames Video.mp4"));

                for (int i = 0; !flag; i++) {
                    File imagesFile = new File(params[0].getParentFile(), String.format(params[0].getName(), i));

                    if(!imagesFile.exists()){
                        break;
                    }
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagesFile.getAbsolutePath());

                    sequenceEncoder.encodeImage(bitmap);

                    publishProgress(i);

                }

                sequenceEncoder.finish();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

    }
```

But the line  - ***sequenceEncoder.encodeImage(bitmap);*** is showing following errors :-

Multiple markers at this line
    - The type java.awt.image.BufferedImage cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files...
    - The method encodeImage(BufferedImage) from the type SequenceEncoder refers to the missing type 
     BufferedImage...

it is asking me to configure build path. I've tried like everything, but in vain.
What should I do next???

Comment: `java.awt classes` are not present in Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java.awt` classes are not present in Android. You should try [JavaCV](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv) for Video encoding or as I see jcodec added Android version on September 14 2013. You should download android version from https://github.com/jcodec/jcodec and add that into your project.

Comment: But as per the library **[jcodec](http://jcodec.org/)**, sample project for android in that is using same code and its apk is working (downloaded from same link). So i preffered to use that library.

Comment: `The type java.awt.image.BufferedImage cannot be resolved. ` as your error shows you are trying to use `BufferedImage` from `java.awt` package which is not present in Android. `java.awt` is present in only desktop version of java. I think you have download .jar file from here http://jcodec.org/downloads.html which is old I think 
`jcodec-0.1.5.jar 05/20/2013` they added Android version on September 14 2013.

Comment: I downloaded the same thing. but its asking me to add BufferedImage in sequenceEncoder.encodeImage(bitmap) instead of bitmap.